# Munkres section 48 exercise 13 - continuous function space in the fine topology is a Baire space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, baire-category

The following is an exercise in Munkres topology.

> Let $X$ be a topological space; let $Y$ be a complete metric space. Show that $C(X, Y)$ is a Baire space in the fine topology. [$Hint$: Given basis elements $B(f_i, \delta_i)$ such that $\delta_1 \leq 1$ and $\delta_{i+1} \leq \delta_i/3$ and $f_{i+1} \in B(f_i, \delta_i/3)$, show that $\bigcap B(f_i, \delta_i) \neq\emptyset$.]

The following is the definition of fine topology in $C(X, Y)$.

> Given $f \in C(X, Y)$, and given a positive continuous function $\delta : X \to R_+$ on $X$, let $B(f, \delta)$ = $\{g : d(f(x), g(x)) < \delta (x)\ $for all $ x \in X\}$.

I can't get started. It is trivial that there exists a function in $\bigcap B(f_i, \delta_i)$, but how can I prove that it is a 'continuous' function? Also, I can't understand how the hint is related to the question(How can I proceed further if I prove the hint?).

Comment: To prove the Baire Category theorem, you show that a countable nested intersection of open "balls" is nonempty. (Do you know the proof of the BCT?) Perhaps the hint has the balls shrink quickly so that the intersection will contain a single function, the limit of the sequence $f_i$. Do you know any theorems that say the limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be unnecessary by now, but there’s no reason to leave this question unanswered.

I’ll answer your last question first. Suppose that $G_n$ is a dense, open subset of $C(X,Y)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and let $G=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}G_n$; we want to show that $G$ is dense in $C(X,Y)$. To that end let $U$ be any non-empty open set in $C(X,Y)$, and let $f_i\in U$; there is a positive $\delta_1\le 1$ such that $B(f_1,\delta_1)\subseteq U\cap G_1$. Given $f_i$ and $\delta_i$ for some $i\in\Bbb Z^+$, let $f_{i+1}\in B(f_i,\delta_i/3)$; there is a positive $\delta_{i+1}\le\delta_i/3$ such that $B(f_{i+1},\delta_{i+1})\subseteq B(f_i,\delta_i)\cap G_{i+1}$. Clearly

$$\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}B(f_i,\delta_i)\subseteq U\cap\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}G_i=U\cap G\,,$$

so you’re done if you can show that $\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}B(f_i,\delta_i)\ne\varnothing$. Note that **every** function in $\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}B(f_i,\delta_i)$ is continuous, because the sets $B(f_i,\delta_i)$ are subsets of $C(X,Y)$.

For each $x\in X$ the sequence $\langle f_i(x):i\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is Cauchy in $Y$, so it converges to some $f(x)\in Y$. This defines a function $f:X\to Y$ that is in $\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}B(f_i,\delta_i)$ iff it is continuous, so all that remains is to show that $f$ is continuous.

Let $x_0\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$. There is an $i\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $$d\big(f_i(x_0),f(x_0)\big)<\delta_i(x_0)<\frac{\epsilon}6\,,$$ and since $f_i$ and $\delta_i$ are continuous, there is an open nbhd $U$ of $x_0$ such that $$d\big(f_i(x),f_i(x_0)\big)<\frac{\epsilon}2\quad\text{and}\quad|\delta_i(x)-\delta_i(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}6$$ whenever $x\in U$. But then

$$\begin{align*}
d\big(f(x),f(x_0)\big)&\le d\big(f(x),f_i(x)\big)+d\big(f_i(x),f_i(x_0)\big)+d\big(f_i(x_0),f(x_0)\big)\\
&<\delta_i(x)+\frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}6\\
&<\delta_i(x_0)+\frac{\epsilon}6+\frac{2\epsilon}3\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}6+\frac{5\epsilon}6\\
&=\epsilon\,,
\end{align*}$$

so $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. And $x_0\in X$ was arbitrary, so $f\in C(X,Y)$, and we’re done.

Answer (score 0):

I will refer to results in *Munkres*.

Essentially, you slightly modify the proof of Theorem 48.2. The hint tells you exactly how to construct the nested sequence $\bar{U}_1 \supset \bar{U}_2 \supset \cdots$.

To make the construction valid, you need to prove $C(X,Y)$ is regular and it's quite easy.

Further, to show $\cap B(f_i, \delta_i) \neq \emptyset$, notice that $\{f_i\}$ are Cauchy in $C(X,Y)$ in the uniform topology, which is complete by Theorem 43.5.